# Windows HttpClient response header invalid character

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, character-encoding, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using HttpClient postAsync method for posting and retriving json. It's working like a charm. 
But if server return "Ö" character in response header's any field, it throws below exception.

```
System.ArgumentException ---> System.ArgumentException: [net_WebHeaderInvalidControlChars]
Arguments:
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.7.60408.0&File=System.Net.dll&Key=net_WebHeaderInvalidControlChars
Parameter name: name
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndGetResponse>b__d(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Header are ASCII only. See RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616

Umlaute in the Header are just a protocol Violation and will throw an exception.

Comment: I looked around a little, but did not yet find a way to just ignore invalid headers... Seems like HttpClient (on SL/WinRT) simply is not able to handle requests/responses with invalid chars in the header...